# Do I need to define a virtual destructor even if the base and derived class only use primitive data types?

Tags: c++

According to the C++ standard: 5.3.5/4:

> If the static type of the operand [of the delete operator] is
>   different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class
>   of the operand's dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual
>   destructor or the behaviour is undefined.

Does this apply even for something such as:

```
class B
{
    public:
    virtual void f() const = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;
};

class D : public B
{
    public:
    explicit D(int x) : x_ {x} {}

    void f() const override;
    void g() override;

    private:
    int x_;
};
```

In this case neither D nor B has anything to deallocate, so shouldn't it no longer be required to provide virtual destructors? Or is this still undefined behavior?

Comment: Just follow what the standard says, if the dynamic type is different and you don't have a virtual destructor then it's UB. Trying to see how this UB could or should be harmless is irrelevant.

Comment: If you `delete` an instance of D through B*, B needs to have a polymorphic destructor.

Comment: Compiler might consider than UB paths are unreachable, and so doesn't generate that path code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement from the standard you quote means that a sample like   (using your class `B` and `D`)

```
int main()
{
    B *object = new D;
    delete object;
}
```

has undefined behaviour if `B` does not have a `virtual` destructor.

No exceptions to that rule.

It doesn't matter what the classes (or their member functions) do or don't do.   It is the non-virtual destructor in `B` that causes the delete expression (`delete object`) to have undefined behaviour.   No exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The standard doesn't make any exceptions predicated on the contents of the classes.

I would say, "Yes, you need `virtual` destructors."